# DIsplaying Div Beyond Its Parent Container CSS

Tags: css

I have this div that starts off at a distance from the top:

[image]

The problem is that, when I start to scroll up, the rounded image is hidden:

[image]

I am very sorry that I could not reproduce the issue, as this is a custom CSS used on Notion -- meaning that I couldn't duplicate a website for testing purposes.

What I want is for the rounded image to appear on the top of the page, as opposed to being partially cut off as in the second image. The image should be perfectly round, even if being scrolled up.

In more simple terms, I want the rounded image to display even outside of the `notion-app` div, which is shown in the first image that starts off at an offset from the top.

Do anyone have a suggestion of removing the problem?

**EDIT** I already tried z-index, but that doesn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried in terms of `z-index` that "*didn't help*"? It depends on your HTML structure, but `z-index` is indeed the way to go. You just might have to adjust the hierarchy so you don't have a parent / child conflict.

Comment: depends on What position you have set for this .. there are multiple ways,
Position: relative, 
Marin-Top:
z-index;
overflow: visible/auto

Answer (score 1):

Give the #notion-app of `overflow: visible;`

```
#notion-app{
 overflow: visible;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

read sample docs on w3school for reference